# Way to Convert Python2 Unicode to std::string with swig

Tags: python-2.7, c++11, ctypes, swig, swig-template

#define SWIG_PYTHON_2_UNICODE is notworking in python2,this is the file .i,PyUnicode_FromString can map std string to unicode

```
%include <std_pair.i> 
%include <std_vector.i> 
%include <std_string.i> 
%template() std::pair<std::string,int>; 
%template(PairVector) std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int> >; 
%template(StringVector) std::vector<std::string>;

%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_2_UNICODE
%}

%{ 
#include "example.h" 

%} 
 %typemap(out) std::string %{
$result = PyUnicode_FromString($1.c_str());
%}

%include "example.h"
```

How to convert a python2 unicode string  to  c++ std::string in swig?

Comment: Could ypu please add the *example.h* code?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Provide a [mcve] and any error messages.

Answer (score -1):

```
 %include <std_pair.i> 
 %include <std_vector.i> 
 %include <std_wstring.i> 
 %template() std::pair<std::wstring,int>; 
 %template(PairVector) std::vector<std::pair<std::wstring,int> >; 
 %template(StringVector) std::vector<std::wstring>;

 %begin %{
 #define SWIG_PYTHON_2_UNICODE
 %}

 %{ 
    #include "example.h" 

 %} 


  %include "example.h"
```

wstring works